# Specifying the columns of the datatable in a general method C#

Tags: c#

I already have the code that specify columns of the `dataTable` but what I want is to create a general method that has in her parameters: `ColumnName` and types.
How can I do that?

This is my code:

```
column = dt.Columns.Add();
column.ColumnName = "IPPName";
column.DataType = typeof(String);

column = dt.Columns.Add();
column.ColumnName = "tagName";
column.DataType = typeof(String);

column = dt.Columns.Add();
column.ColumnName = "time";
column.DataType = typeof(String);

column = dt.Columns.Add();
column.ColumnName = "value";
column.DataType = typeof(Double);

column = dt.Columns.Add();
column.ColumnName = "qtity";
column.DataType = typeof(Double);
```

Comment: and I didnt know functions are she :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont know if I understand question correctly. Do you want to implement something like this ?

```
      public DataTable  CreateDataTable(Dictionary<string,Type> columns)
      {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            foreach( var key in columns)
            {
                var column = dt.Columns.Add();
                column.ColumnName = key.Key;
                column.DataType = key.Value;
            }
            return dt;

        }


        public void CreateNewDataTable()
        {
            var columns = new Dictionary<string, Type>()
                {
                    {"column", typeof (string)}
                };
            var dt = CreateDataTable(columns);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

An additional way to solve it using extensionmethods. I believe it is a tad easier to follow than @adt answer and more useful since it can be called on an already existing `DataTable`.

If you need help regarding extensionmethods, have a look at [this description](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx) or just ask :)

```
public static class DataTableExtentions {
  public static void AddColumn(this DataTable table, string columnName, Type columnType)
  {
    var col = table.Columns.Add();
    col.ColumnName = columnName;
    col.DataType = columnType;
  }
}
```

And it would be called like this:

```
column = dt.AddColumn("IPPName", typeof(String));

column = dt.AddColumn("tagName", typeof(String));

column = dt.AddColumn("time", typeof(String));

column = dt.AddColumn("value", typeof(Double));

column = dt.AddColumn("qtity", typeof(Double));
```